# how to add new columns on multiple data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add new column ['Name'] on multiple identical data frames such as df1, df2, df3, df4, df5.

here is my code

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
lists = ["btcusd", "ethusd", "usdtusd", "adausd", "dogeusd"]

for i in range(len(lists)): 
    df[i+1]['Name'] = lists[i]
```

and I got this error
[image]

Basically, I am trying to make shortcode for the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDgWF.png)

please, let me know how to archive this

Comment: It appears that `df` is a DataFrame defined somewhere else in your program which has MultiIndex columns without `Name` at the top level. You most likely meant to select from the list of DataFrames like `df_list[i+1]['Name'] = lists[i]`

Comment: omg... you are right. I just changed the code and it worked.. I didn't notice it was `df` not `df_list` .. thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['B'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['D'])
df5 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['E'])

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
lists = ["btcusd", "ethusd", "usdtusd", "adausd", "dogeusd"]

for df in df_list:
    df[lists] = ''
    print(df.columns)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There is no data in the dataframe, just the columns to show how you could add the list of columns.

Comment: @gwandg If this answers your question, kindly accept by clicking the 'tick' mark. Thanks.

Comment: Im so sorry for such a late response and thank you so much for your help. What I am trying to do is make a short code for this code

# make a copy of each data frame
df1_copy = df1.copy()
df2_copy = df2.copy()
df3_copy = df3.copy()
df4_copy = df4.copy()
df5_copy = df5.copy()

df1_copy['Name'] = lists[0]
df2_copy['Name'] = lists[1]
df3_copy['Name'] = lists[2]
df4_copy['Name'] = lists[3]
df5_copy['Name'] = lists[4]

# append all of dataframe into one 
df = df1_copy.copy()
df = df.append([df2_copy, df3_copy, df4_copy, df5_copy])
df.info()